# Update list in-place, converting 'True'/'False' elements to 1/0

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In python, supposed I have a list:

```
l = [ 'True', 'False', 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo' ]
```

and I want to convert the *strings* `'True'` or `'False'` to `1` or `0`, what is the best way to do this and still retain the index that the value had originally? i.e. the output would look like:

```
l = [  1, 0, 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo' ]
```

Comment: Did you mean the strings 'True','False' not the booleans True,False?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension is your friend:

```
>>> l = [ 'True', 'False', 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo'] 
>>> mapping = {"True": 1, "False": 0}
>>> [mapping.get(x, x) for x in l]
```

Comment: Could go one step further with `mapping = {"True": 1, "False": 0}.get`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> replace = {'True':1, 'False':0}
>>> my_list = [ 'True', 'False', 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo' ]
>>> [replace.get(e,e) for e in my_list]
[1, 0, 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would offer a more robust solution if your list's items are `on`, `off`, `yes`, `no` etc (*refer to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool)*).

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
def convert_str_to_bool(l):
    result = []
    for item in l:
        try:
            result.append(strtobool(item))
        except:
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

**Sample Output:**

```
>>> l = [ 'True', 'False', 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo' ] 
>>> print convert_str_to_bool(l)
[1, 0, 'myname', 1, 0, 'foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop

```
for i in l:

    if i == 'True':

        a = l.index(i)

        b = l.remove(i)

        l.insert(a, 1)

    elif i == 'False':

        a = l.index(i)

        b = l.remove(i)

        l.insert(a, 0)

print(l)
```